# Event watcher failing on dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

Thank you in advance for any help! :)

I am using javascript to add fields to a document but the element monitor only works on hard coded fields.

For example in the code below, lozfield is monitored for change which works fine initially.
However, if you click the populate button and repopulate with exactly the same input field, the watch no longer works.
In debug, the field has EVENT next to it... until it is repopulated at which point the EVENT disappears.
(apologies for my probably incorrect terminology!).

```js
$("#lozfield").change(function() {
  alert("lozfield-CHANGED");
});

$("#populate").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("lozcontainer").innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="lozfield" value="ABC">';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lozcontainer">
  <input type="text" id="lozfield" value="ABC">
</div>
<input id="populate" type="button" value="POPULATE">
```

Comment: Or change value instead of all input or re assign event to the new input.

Comment: That event is only attached to the element that exists. innerHTML will replace your current element with a new element.

Comment: The duplicate has your answer, however you can avoid the problem entirely by replacing the `innerHTML` call with just `$('#lozfield').val('ABC');`. This resets the value without destroying the original element and losing its event handler.

Comment: Thanks all - just to be clear I actually was just illustrating the problem - really I want to add the elements dynamically without them existing in the first place. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate your event to a higher element - which in your case I'd suggest is `lozcontainer`

```js
$("#lozcontainer").change("#lozfield", function() {
  alert("lozfield-CHANGED");
});

$("#populate").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("lozcontainer").innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="lozfield" value="ABC">';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lozcontainer">
  <input type="text" id="lozfield" value="ABC">
</div>
<input id="populate" type="button" value="POPULATE">
```

Comment: Just FYI you don't need the first argument in the `change()` invocation here, as it's event data, not the delegated selector.

Comment: You could also add eventListener when creating the element `$("#lozcontainer").html('<input...').click(onClickFunction)`

Comment: Thank you all, really appreciate it.
Thank you @jamiec for your answer - I think that probably solves my problem.

Comment: @tallberg - may I ask how I could add the event listener at the same time? I did try adding script code to the innerHTML property but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @LaurenceJones you need to use jquery `.html()` - `innerHTML?` is not jquery. See my example.

Comment: @LaurenceJones example of tallberg code: https://jsfiddle.net/xy8h0k34/